# Doctrine2.5 getReference and merge update no works

Tags: doctrine-orm, merge

I have a strange problem with Doctrine 2.5 while try update my table UserProfile where my column BusinessActivity is a foreign key.

CASE 1) USING getReference()

`update` works, but not on column BusinessActivity.

```
$myid = 6;
$businessActivity = $entityManger->getReference('BusinessActivity', 6);

//$businessActivity proxy object was created correctly with id 6
$userDetails->setBusinessActivity($businessActivity);

$entityManger->merge($userDetails);
```

//FLUSH AND COMMIT

CASE 2) CREATING OBJECT FROM DB WITH REPOSITORY WORKS

```
$rep               = $entityManager->getRepository('BusinessActivity');
$businessActivity  = $rep->findOneBy(array('idActivity' => 6);

$userDetails->setBusinessActivity($businessActivity);

//FLUSH AND COMMIT
```

Naturally, I already have id and I didn't want to execute a query with findOneBy.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Did you tried to use `$entityManager->merge($userDetails);` with the case 2?

Comment: Yes i used merge with case 2 and works. I don't understand because case 1 doesn't Work totally, column business activity is updated always to value 1 (i checked with xdebug and i tried other values). If i use persist works, but i have to update that record.